# dump gtk2 elements to png

Tags: themes, gtk-2

i want do dump every gtk2 element in single png files. So that i can analyze them for creating gtk3 themes. This questions is only about the way how to dump every element like buttons scrollbars etc to single png files , not more !! The other converting process is done by another script.

regards bluedxca93

---

i did now managed to grab non hover states with scripts like these:
Example : inactiveb is a file containing:

> sleep 1 ;import -window "inactivecheckradio" inactivecheckradio.png;  wmctrl -c inactivecheckradio

printinactivecheckbutton

> ./analyzecheckradio & ./inactiveb

analyzecheckradio is  a program that shows the radio buttons ( either pygtk or C/glade).
How do i print the hovered states to disk ?. something like xdotool or xmacroplay + sleep is anoing when window decorator changes or theme has highly another widths.

regrads bluedxca93

Answer (score 3):

Imagemagick will do what you need. Basic command line is:

Code:
convert +append image1.jpg image2.jpg product.jpg

The two images are placed side by side; use -append for a 'top to bottom' arrangement. With this you can easily write a script to process all of the files.

If you don't already have it installed, this might be a good starting point: 
http://www.imagemagick.org

Source: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/194015-putting-two-images-together.html

Hope that gets you part of the way.

Comment: yeah aour tip helped a bit. its also good to use the import tool from imagemagick and imageclipper from google code project. Thats also why i gave you the bounty. The problem is that the matter isn`t solved now, but i tought your answer was worth the bounty !